# Dragging photoshop image to illustrator and scale is a lot smaller - Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

I've been trying to place or drag something from photoshop into illustrator but whatever way I do it it comes in as really small. The artboard sizes are both 1080 x 1080 px I took screenshots of all the details of both illustrator and photoshop windows and dimensions. I don't think I've usually encountered problems as I would drag images directly to illustrator all the time and they never came in as really small so there must be something I changed or need to change in this case.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to be working right. A pixel **unit** in illustrator is 1/72th of an inch. Your images pixels are 1/300th of an inch appart. There is no problem as such now you just have 2 different sizes of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the resolution of your image in Photoshop to **72 Pixel/Inch.** You can do this via *Image Size*: **first (!)** uncheck *Resample* (the units change to centimeters or inches, it's ok), then change the resolution from 300 to 72 ppi.

Also you can export your image for Web (*Export* —> *Save for Web (Legacy)*). It changes the resolution to 72 ppi automatically. If you need transparency in you image you can choose *PNG-24* and select *Transparency* checkbox.

[image: Photoshop Image Size]

[image: Photoshop Save for Web]

[image: Illustrator Artboard]